# Clustering by assigning weights to the attributes

Tags: excel, data-mining

I have a data set in excel sheet which I need to cluster it by assigning weights. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function that computes the distance between two points by  attribute weights into account. An example of this would be weighted euclidean distance

Specifically if there are k attributes for each point in your dataset and if the corresponding weights for the attributes are d1,d2,..,dk then distance between two points X and Y is

d(X,Y) = sum(di * (Xi-Yi)^2) i=1,2..k where Xi is the value of ith attribute for the point X.

If the weights are inverse of the variance of the attribute it reduces to mahalanobis distance

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance

Once you define the distance function you can use K-means to cluster your data.